# System V Unix and swap area

Tags: unix, virtual-memory

So, I have had some problem with understanding when I started to learn mechanism of virtual memory in Unix System. So, there is `structure proc` that contains comprehensive information about any process in a system (*I deem that `proc` has been replaced to `tusk_struct`,but conception is actually today)*. `struct proc` consists address that directs to `struct as` that directs to list of `struct seg`.[image]

*Sorry for my draft!* Roughly it looks like on the picture. So, my answer affects virtual memory. There is `segvn_data` that is linked with `vnode`. `vnode` composes part of File System and take it upon itself of any work with file, including changing on a hard drive. Is that right that one of segment can process such pages that is mapped by `vnode`? Why should they both use `swap area`? What is responsible `swap area`?

PS: when does segment need to change swap area?

PPS: all processes do need to have swap area? When vnode requires that segment    maps in swap area?

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it's not about programming as such. It would be a better fit for our sister site https://unix.stackexchange.com

Comment: I think there is some misunderstanding of the nature of these structures. IIRC, seg refers the page cache, not to the academic segments of a process. IIRC vnode is part of the structure that defines the mapping of the process address space to the swap (paging) area.